# Error running ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js in GitLab CI

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, gitlab-ci, cucumberjs

I am setting up a CI build for my node project. Although my `npm run test` works as expected in my local environment, the gitlab ci is throwing an exception.

The test command fails in:
`> nyc ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js ./test/BDD/**/*.feature -f node_modules/cucumber-pretty -f json:./test/report/cucumber_report.json --require-module ts-node/register --require ./test/**/*.ts`

> Error: Parse error in 'test/BDD/step-definition.ts': (1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'import { StepDefinitionCode, Given, When, Then, StepDefinitionOptions } from "cucumber";'
>      at /builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/cucumber/src/cli/helpers.js:66:13
>      at Array.forEach ()
>      at forEach (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/cucumber/src/cli/helpers.js:54:10)
>      at Generator.next ()
>      at Generator.tryCatcher (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>      at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:97:49)
>      at /builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:201:15
>      at getTestCases (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/helpers.js:102:18)
>      at getTestCases (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/cucumber/src/cli/helpers.js:32:13)
>      at Generator.next ()
>      at Generator.tryCatcher (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>      at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:97:49)
>      at Promise._settlePromise (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:579:26)
>      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
>      at Promise._settlePromises (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
>      at _drainQueueStep (/builds/cristianmercado19/basic-package/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)

Screenshot:

[image]

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration:

```yaml
image: node:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

testing_testing:
  stage: test
  script: npm test
```

My cucumber folder structure:

[image]

I have tried...

- to get the artifacts and compare the `cucumber` folder with my local. Both are the same.
- removing nyc
- updating packages versions
- this minimum script also fails `"test": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js test/BDD/**/*.feature --require-module ts-node/register --require ./test/**/*.ts",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know for what reason this script does not work in the GitLab CI (works in my local)

`"test": "nyc cucumber-js -f node_modules/cucumber-pretty -f json:./test/report/cucumber_report.json --require test/**/*.ts ./test/BDD/**/*.feature",`

Instead, I have extracted that configuration in a `cucumber.js` file

```
let common = [
  'test/**/*.feature',
  '--require-module ts-node/register',
  '--require test/**/*.ts',
  '--format node_modules/cucumber-pretty',
  '--format json:./test/report/cucumber_report.json'
].join(' ');

module.exports = {
  default: common,
};
```

And replaced `test` script by:

`"test": "nyc ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -p default",`