# CucumberJS not compiling in typescript in Gitlab CI

Tags: typescript, gitlab-ci, cucumberjs

**NPM script**: `"cucumber": "cucumber-js --require features/tests.setup.js --require features/**/*.ts"`.

**tests.setup.js**:

```js
require('ts-node').register({
  transpileOnly: true,
  compilerOptions: {
    "module": "commonjs",
  },
});
```

**Gitlab CI error**:

```
> cucumber-js --require features/tests.setup.js --require features/**/*.ts
Error: Parse error in 'features/step-definitions/steps.calculus-triangle.ts': (1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'import {Then} from 'cucumber''
    at events.forEach.event (/builds/Ambroise-Rabier/mandala-vibratoire/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/helpers.js:110:13)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at getTestCases (/builds/Ambroise-Rabier/mandala-vibratoire/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/helpers.js:81:10)
    at _bluebird.default.each (/builds/Ambroise-Rabier/mandala-vibratoire/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/helpers.js:58:35)
```

It work in local (win 10), but on Gitlab CI it seem to ignore typescript compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something working with the help of [Error running ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js in GitLab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422245/error-running-node-modules-bin-cucumber-js-in-gitlab-ci/57434997#57434997), however I am not using `nyc`, so here the solution using only **cucumberjs**.

**NPM script**: `"cucumber": "cucumber-js --profile default"`.

**Create** `cucumber.js` file at root of your project with content:

```js
let common = [
  '--require features/tests.setup.js',
  '--require features/**/*.ts',
].join(' ');

module.exports = {
  default: common,
};
```

**Relevant doc**: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#profiles